# How to print model properties to excel?

Tags: django

I want to export my table into the csv file .
But some of the fields in my table are properties.

For example those: 'current_tobe_payed', 'current_balance', 'current_period','total_payment', 'total_discount'

```
def export_leaseterm_csv(request):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="leaseterm.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['lease', 'increase', 'amount', 'is_terminated', 'current_tobe_payed', 'current_balance', 'current_period','total_payment', 'total_discount'])

        leaseterms = LeaseTerm.objects.all().values_list('start_period', 'end_period', 'lease', 'increase', 'amount', 'is_terminated', 'current_tobe_payed', 'current_balance', 'current_period','total_payment', 'total_discount')
        for leaseterm in leaseterms:
            writer.writerow(leaseterm)

        return response
```

I am getting `Cannot resolve keyword 'current_tobe_payed' into field.`

How Can I overcome it?

UPDATE:

I have updated the view based on answer:

```
def export_leaseterm_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="leaseterm.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)


    leaseterms = serializers.serialize( "python", LeaseTerm.objects.all())

    for leaseterm in leaseterms:
        writer.writerow([value[0] for value in leaseterm])

    return response
```

The output received

f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p

When expected is:

33  8788    -6105.00    0   0   6105.00 555.00  False   True    False

28  4545    -5537.00    1120.00 15.00   6657.00 556.00  False   True    False

32  6789    -3108.00    0   0   3108.00 777.00  False   True    False

34  2222    0.00    0   0   0.00    777.00  False   True    False

Comment: Yes my table does have data . I display it on my report already and then I want to print it out into excel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly `current_tobe_payed` is on for the properties that you speak of. A property cannot be used in a values_list call. Change your code to:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize( "python", LeaseTerm.objects.all() )

for leaseterm in  data:
    writer.writerow([value for value in leaseterm['fields'].values()])
```

This serializer creates a standard python object from our model object which allows us to iterate through their fields. And we get a little help from a list comphrehension.

Comment: Thank you !
It does work but the output is weird 
start_period,end_period,lease,increase,amount,is_terminated,current_tobe_payed, current_balance, current_period,total_payment, total_discount
"{'description': None, 'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 2, 19, 29, 47, 686000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_active': True, 'start_period': 1, 'modified': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 17, 6, 23, 421000, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'increase': Decimal('3.00'), 'amount': Decimal('556.00'), 'version': 1478883036718200L, 'end_period': 12, 'is_terminated': False, 'lease': 13}",conditions.leaseterm,28

Comment: This is how it looks now:
start_period,end_period,lease,increase,amount,is_terminated
f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p
f,m,p

Comment: Really sorry , I got the syntax mixed up. Please try now

Comment: Thank you . It is working now. Is there a documentation I can read about it .
I want to display only certain fields . And have some filter to display only  rows where balance will be negative.

Comment: What I have done here is a python 'list comphrehension' with a little help from a django serializer. Python list comphrensions have lots of good tutorials, but this particular example may not be covered. After a readin one or two, if you find that it's still not clear, post another question, giving this code and I will post a detailed explaination on that